# My integer wont update when i think it should

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int currentPrice = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblCurrentPrice.Text = "0";

        if (checkSugarF.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 25;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (CheckLettering.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 50;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkSparklers.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 35;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkCandles.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 25;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkCandleHold.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 15;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkCenterp.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 80;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkTierSep.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 20;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
        if (checkRibbon.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 75;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

I want currentPrice to update as each check box gets checked but it stays on 0.
I am not sure if i am using the right syntax.
Also i am fairly new to forms.

Comment: have you tried to debug the code? Is it really going inside the if

Comment: You need to register an Event Handler for your CheckBoxes *CheckStateChanged* event. Look into [CheckStateChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstatechanged?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the event CheckedChanged event for each checkbox. Now you are checking the condition inside the form's contructor.

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            currentPrice += 75;
            lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are doing this in your constructor so that piece of code is executed only once.

You need to connect the event `CheckedChanged` of your UI components and than  execute the update accordingly to the `Checked` value, something similar to this:

```
  private void checkSugarF_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkSugarF.Checked) 
            currentPrice += 25;
        else 
            currentPrice -=25;

        lblCurrentPrice.Text = currentPrice.ToString();

    }
```